# The number of loop cut didnt increase when i use scroll wheel up and down

Tags: modeling, loop, mouse

I have watch several tutorial that say when using loop cut by using Ctrl + R, we can increase and decrease the number of loop cut by using scroll wheel up and down, but when I scroll, nothing happens.

This picture is when using the loop cut
[image]

And this picture is after pressing Ctrl + R. I can only choose where to cut by moving the mouse up and down. No matter how much i scroll, it just doesn't have any effect. Is there any solution?
[image]

Comment: Just to make sure that there isn't confusion over the term "scroll", it means rolling the wheel on your mouse like you would to navigate on a website. It does not mean moving the moving the mouse itself up and down. Is that what you've been doing? If it doesn't work you might have changed your keymap settings by accident.

Comment: I'm still new in blender and I just realized my mistake in which i have to scroll the wheel first before left clicking. Thanks for the help